# Prometheus Alertmanager: Blackbox exporter alerts based on instance

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

We use blackbox_exporter "fail_if_body_matches_regexp:" to check different internal monitor pages. The problem is when developers use many different "words" for "failed_application". Some of the words are actually present on some of the other monitor pages, when service is OK.
Is it possible to differentiate on instance in alers.rules in some way? Or is there other way to solve that issue?

This is probably not work...but you might understand where i am going with this...
- alert: Error on monitor page
    expr: probe_failed_due_to_regex == 1
    for: 1m
    *instance: serve1, server2*
    labels:
      severity: error

- alert: Feil på monitor side
  expr: probe_failed_due_to_regex == 1
  for: 1m
  *instance: server2, server3*
  labels:
    severity: error
  annotations:

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make the regex more specific, you'd have to create a new blackbox module per set of failure words.